# MergeFrom* vs. ParseFrom* in Google's protobuf library

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I can't seem to find a clear distinction between the `MergeFrom*` and the `ParseFrom*` methods of the [MessageLite](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite) class in protobuf.

I am trying to minimize the amount of data copying I have to do, so I have written the following code below to decode a length-prefixed-message:

```
bool StreamMessageDelimiter::receiveWithLengthPrefix(Message& message)
{
    google::protobuf::uint32 messageSize;
    auto_ptr<google::protobuf::uint8> prefixBuf(new google::protobuf::uint8[sizeof(messageSize)]);
    int receivedBytes = receiveNBytes(prefixBuf.get(), sizeof(messageSize));
    if(receivedBytes != sizeof(messageSize))
    {
        return false;
    }

    CodedInputStream prefixInput(prefixBuf.get(), sizeof(messageSize));
    prefixInput.ReadLittleEndian32(&messageSize);

    google::protobuf::uint8* payloadBuf = new google::protobuf::uint8[messageSize];
    receivedBytes = receiveNBytes(payloadBuf, messageSize);
    if(receivedBytes != messageSize)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ArrayInputStream rawInput(payloadBuf, messageSize);
    CodedInputStream codedInput(&rawInput);

    if(!message.MergeFromCodedStream(&codedInput))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My question is does using the [MergeFromCodedStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.MergeFromCodedStream.details) cause `message` to take ownership of the `payloadBuf`, or does `message` make a copy of the underlying data? If `message` does indeed make a copy, then I obviously should use an `auto_ptr` for `payloadBuf` like I did for the `prefixBuf`.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for [ArrayInputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl_lite#ArrayInputStream.ArrayInputStream.details):

> "data" remains the property of the caller but must remain valid until
>   the stream is destroyed.

So no, it doesn't take ownership, and you should make sure to release the memory at the right time.

I think you might be confused by the use of the word `Merge` in the function names. It does not come to say "data is merged from the passed buffer" (which I think caused you to consider ownership), but rather "data is merged into the message". So, `Parse` calls `Clear()` before filling the message, whereas `Merge` uses the message you passed directly as-is.

Answer (score 6):

First of all `MergeFrom*` do not work like `ParseFrom*` method.
The first one work like `MergeFrom` from Message class:

> Singular fields will be overwritten, except for embedded messages which will be merged. Repeated fields will be concatenated.

`ParseFrom` is a wraper, and simply call `Clear` before call to `MergeFrom`:

> Clear() avoids freeing memory, assuming that any memory allocated to hold parts of the message will be needed again to hold the next message. If you actually want to free the memory used by a Message, you must delete it.

So until your Message is Cleared, all repeated fields will agregate the new data.

The data stored in the serialized stream is [Varint encoded](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), therefore parsing is done by interpreting the data in stream and copying into Message object fields.

The message itself will not need the buffer after the parsing is done.